# Generalized Linear Mixed Model

Tags: logistic, spss, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, mixed-model

I have three independent variables (all binary) and two interaction variables that I would like to test for their effect on the dependent variable "Awareness_level". This dependent variable is also binary.

I assigned participants randomly to one of 8 different conditions. In the assigned condition they were exposed to 1 of 8 advertisements (advertisements were varied based on different combinations of the 3 independent variables). All participants were asked the same questions to assess awareness: one question to assess recall and one question to assess recognition.

I restructured the data in SPSS so that for each subject there are two rows of data. The first row (index variable awareness_type is 1) shows recall and the second row (index variable awareness_type is 2) shows recognition. I created the variable awareness_level as a target variable. See picture (might be more clear).

[image]
To add an intercept to the model that is different for every participant, I choose to fit a binomial logistic mixed model by running a Generalized linear mixed model with a binomial regression in SPSS.

I think I should add all the independent variables (used to create the different conditions) + the interaction terms as fixed factors, while adding a random effect for subject ID.

**Should I also add the index variable "awareness_type" as a independent variable?**

I used this manual from SPSS as a basis (although it is for multinomial logistic mixed model) http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.cs%2Fglmm_cablesurvey_howto.htm

They interpret the fit of the model by looking at the accuracy / classification table. But if I'm correct you should compare the accuracy rate to the proportional by chance accuracy rate right? **How do I calculate this one?**

**And wouldn't it be better to assess the model fit based on the information criterion instead of accuracy rate? And which one is better than, Bayesian or Akaike corrected?**

Would be great if you can help me!!